# stacktrace at startup when missing_cache_strategy set to false for ehcache

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

I've upgraded hibernate from version 5.0.1.Final to 5.3.4.Final I've also upgraded ehcache to version 3.5.2

In my spring context, I've got the following properties set for hibernate

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="nl.company.project.mssqlutils.FlexibleSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show.sql:false}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">${hibernate.connection.release.strategy:after_statement}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.javax.cache.missing_cache_strategy">create</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.javax.cache.provider">org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.javax.cache.uri">classpath:ehcache.xml</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">${hibernate.use.second.level.cache:true}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">${hibernate.use.query.cache:true}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">jcache</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.coordinator_class">jta</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```

My `ehcache.xml` is something like

```
 <config
     xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
     xmlns='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'
     xmlns:jsr107='http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107'
     xsi:schemaLocation="
     http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.0.xsd
     http://www.ehcache.org/v3/jsr107 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-107-ext-3.0.xsd">

 <service>
     <jsr107:defaults enable-management="false" enable-statistics="false">
      <jsr107:cache name="otherCache" template="otherCacheTemplate1"/>
      <jsr107:cache name="otherCache" template="otherCacheTemplate2"/>
     </jsr107:defaults>
 </service>

 <cache-template name="defaultCacheTemplate">
     <expiry>
      <ttl unit="minutes">10</ttl>
     </expiry>
     <heap>1000</heap>
 </cache-template>

 <cache-template name="otherCacheTemplate1">
     <key-type>java.lang.String</key-type>
     <value-type>nl.company.product.domain.OtherClass1</value-type>
     <expiry>
      <ttl unit="minutes">10</ttl>
     </expiry>
     <heap>1000</heap>
 </cache-template>

 <cache-template name="otherCacheTemplate2">
     <key-type>java.lang.String</key-type>
     <value-type>nl.company.product.domain.OtherClass2</value-type>
     <expiry>
      <ttl unit="minutes">10</ttl>
     </expiry>
     <heap>1000</heap>
 </cache-template>

 </config>
```

And in the java code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OtherClass1")
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE, region = "otherCache")
@Data
public class OtherClass1{
  //......
}
```

If I set the property `hibernate.javax.cache.missing_cache_strategy` to `fail`. I get a stacktrace

```
2018-08-21 16:54:06,852 [DASHBOARD][WARN ][RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext.refresh:551 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'otherClass1Dao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/persistenceContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.CacheImplementor] 
21-Aug-2018 16:54:07.154 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2018-08-21 16:54:07,152 [DASHBOARD][ERROR][RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.w.c.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext:350 - Context initialization failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'otherClass1Dao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/persistenceContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.CacheImplementor]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1272) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4792) [catalina.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5256) [catalina.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754) [catalina.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730) [catalina.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1736) [catalina.jar:8.5.32]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.32]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:483) [catalina.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:432) [catalina.jar:8.5.32]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.32]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/persistenceContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.CacheImplementor]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1634) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.cache.spi.CacheImplementor]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.getService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:511) ~[spring-orm-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:495) ~[spring-orm-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1692) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1630) ~[spring-beans-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    ... 70 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.cache.CacheException: On-the-fly creation of JCache Cache objects is not supported [default-update-timestamps-region]
    at org.hibernate.cache.jcache.internal.JCacheRegionFactory.createCache(JCacheRegionFactory.java:115) ~[hibernate-jcache-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cache.jcache.internal.JCacheRegionFactory.getOrCreateCache(JCacheRegionFactory.java:98) ~[hibernate-jcache-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cache.jcache.internal.JCacheRegionFactory.createTimestampsRegionStorageAccess(JCacheRegionFactory.java:155) ~[hibernate-jcache-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cache.spi.support.RegionFactoryTemplate.buildTimestampsRegion(RegionFactoryTemplate.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.EnabledCaching.<init>(EnabledCaching.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:33) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CacheInitiator.initiateService(CacheInitiator.java:24) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.spi.SessionFactoryServiceInitiator.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceInitiator.java:30) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(SessionFactoryServiceRegistryImpl.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.4.Final.jar:5.3.4.Final]
    ... 81 common frames omitted
21-Aug-2018 16:54:07.162 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/dashboard] startup failed due to previous errors
21-Aug-2018 16:54:07.190 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [dashboard] registered the JDBC driver [com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
[2018-08-21 04:54:07,217] Artifact dashboard-war:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

If I set the properties to look for a non-existing cache file I get an error, so the file is read. If the cache file is messed up I see another error so it is interpreted. So it seems that it does read the file, but does not use it to map de cache definitions to the cache defined in my beans.

Answer (score 2):

You are in front of a very interesting problem. The way the Hibernate `JCacheRegionFactory` works in Hibernate 3.5 is the following:

1. Try to get the cache (CacheManager.getCache)
2. If not found, check the `MissingCacheStrategy` and behave accordingly

In your case, `hibernate.javax.cache.missing_cache_strategy` is set at `create`. So it should work and create the cache correctly. Your question wasn't clear about if this is the case. Is it?

However, when passing it to `fail`, you indeed get this error because Hibernate isn't supposed to create a cache. Only to use existing ones. This is to prevent against what we call [spontaneous cache creation](http://www.ehcache.org/blog/2017/03/15/spontaneous-cache-creation.html). The creation of a cache with default values.

In your case, you have a template so the cache would be correctly created. But Hibernate isn't aware of that. So it fails.

You have two solutions:

1. Leave it at `create` and cross your fingers that you never forget to add a template
2. Remove the `jsr107:cache` and just create normal Ehcache `<cache .../>`.

I recommend that second one. It's safer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It's a petty that hibernate is not aware of the created caches.

Comment: No really their fault. The cache doesn't exist before `createCache` is called. So they can't know it will be created from a template instead of default parameters.